# Should I backup the "eclipse" folder?

Tags: eclipse, backup

My "~/eclipse" folder contains the following subfolders: about_files, configuration, dropins, features, p2, plugins, readme.

Is it important to include this folder, or some of its subfolders, in the regular backup of my hard-drive? Or are they just standard files that come with the installation and can always be restored by re-installing Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a backup of the complete eclipse folder makes sense as it contains all the plug-ins which you have installed. Sometimes eclipse breaks because of a new plug-in or just any random problem. Then it's great to have a backup and you don't need to install every plug-in which you had before.